# CSS3 column size and alignment troubles in nested nav lists

Tags: html, css

On a project I'm working on, I currently have the code below (JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/uuv7b5pu/). I get the desired effect. `<li>`s with no nesting just underline on mouseover, those with a few nested items display in a list, and those with a lot of nested items have the `columnise` class, which displays the items in 3 columns.

I'm having problems with the columnised menus. (See the fiddle for a live demo). The main problem is that the cells aren't resizing to accommodate the content. There is only one cell in the site that has this problem, and I haven't been able to get to the root of it...

A secondary problem is that with this particular number of entries, the underline of one of the elements get shunted to the top of the next column, which is very annoying. Note that the underline on mouseover is implemented by fading `bottom-border`. This was done by design since `text-decoration` cannot be animated. I want to know why the border isn't staying with the cell.

Finally, I can't understand why the cells don't stay in square alignment with each other.

Could someone enlighten me as to why these things are happening and how I can fix them? How can I avoid this issue in future designs? I thought this was a good approach initially, but I would welcome a second opinion.

**EDIT in response to comment:**

To summarise:

**1. How do I allow the cells to resize to their content?**

**2. How can I ensure the cell, including the border used for underlining, stays together, instead of the border being moved to the next column as in the fiddle?**

**3. How can I ensure the cells stay square relative to each other? (In the fiddle they are misaligned between columns.)**

**EDIT in response to Tofu Warriors answer:**

1. and 3. are sorted. 2. is still a problem, as can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/05038bgk/

I'm looking for a way to contain each `li` in one column, but still allow the text in each `li` to overflow within itself, just not into the next column.

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Problem</a>
      <ul class="columnise">
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Very long entry</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Underline</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Level 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav
{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

nav ul li
{
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     padding-bottom: 17px;
     padding-top: 17px;
}

nav ul li a
{
    transition: border 0.25s ease-in-out;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

nav ul li > a:hover, a.active
{
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

nav ul li ul
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    transition: visibility 0.25s, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

nav ul:hover li:hover > ul
{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}


nav ul li ul li
{
    margin: 10px;
    width: initial;
    padding:5px;
}

nav ul li ul div
{
    display: block;
}

.columnise
{
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    width:255%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: -82%;
    padding:15px;
    font-size: 23px;
}

a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

Comment: ur question is not clear please explain what u want to do..

Comment: I've clarified some points.

Answer (score 1):

So the reason they are not lining up is because of the margin on the li's within the columns. The columns are already filled entirely so when you add a margin on it the li's start to do this broken overflow type deal and push each other out of the way. The width on your li's can be taken out as well since the column is defining the width for them:

```
nav ul li ul li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Secondly the border wrapping around is happening because it is trying to wrap your text but only the border is showing up. You could do something like `overflow: hidden;` on the columns or just extend the columns width so the li's all fit within to column.

```
  .columnise
    {
        -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 3;
        width:20em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        left: -82%;
        padding:15px;
        font-size: 23px;
    }
```

I hope that answers your questions!

Comment: Ok, this was a great help, thanks! Based on your answer, I changed `nav ul li ul li` to `padding: 0px; padding-top:15px;`, and extended the `width` and removed `white-space` from `.columnise` This solves the `li` squareness and hidden text problems, but the border shoving is still there.  Any ideas for the last part? The updated fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/05038bgk/

Comment: Great! That would be the second block of css in my answer. If you look I expanded your column width to 20em. (20em was about 350% if I kept it in percent), give that a try in fiddle

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately that doesn't work. `20em` is shorter than the `292%` that is currently there, and even setting it to `350%` doesn't solve it. I guess I'm looking for a way to contain each `li` in one column, but still allow the text in each `li` to overflow within itself, just not into the next column.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">

nav
  {
     text-align: center;
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 0.75;
  }

  nav ul
     {
       list-style-type: none;
      width:100%;
         display: inline-flex;
       padding: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-top: 0px;
    }




    nav ul li
      {
       width: 100%;
         position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 17px;
        padding-top: 17px;
       }
     nav ul li ul li{
        width:200px;
       }

      /* nav ul li a
      {
        transition: border 0.25s ease-in-out;
        border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
     } */

     /* nav ul li > a:hover, a.active
          {
          border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
       }
           */
         nav ul li ul
           {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 25px;
            display: block;
            background-color: #0d0d0d;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            transition: visibility 0.25s, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
             visibility: hidden;
           opacity: 0;
          }

        nav ul:hover li:hover > ul
       {
           visibility: visible;
              opacity: 1;
             }


        nav ul li ul li
      {
           margin: 10px;
          width: initial;
          padding:5px;
       }

         nav ul li ul div
        {
           display: block;
         }

       .columnise
      {
        -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
          column-count: 3;
        width:255%;
        white-space: nowrap;
         left: -82%;
        padding:15px;
       font-size: 23px;
      }

      /* a
        {
        color: white;
       text-decoration: inherit;
       } */

      nav ul li a,nav ul li ul li a{
        color: white;
         text-decoration: none;
        }
          nav ul li a:hover,nav ul li ul li a:hover{
        text-decoration: underline;

    }

       </style>
```

This can be a answer tell me if u r satisfied with the solution or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this won't work for me. The `border-bottom` is used for the underline by design, as `text-decoration` can't be animated, and I want the fade effect to be seen on mouseover.